# Django: Creating an M2M relationship through an intermediate table using multiple keys

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, orm

I'm working with an external MySQL database that I've mapped to the Django ORM using the following models:

```py
class SchemaCategory(models.Model):

    schema_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    language_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 255L,blank = True)

    unique_together = (('schema_id','language_id',),)

class Equipment(models.Model):

    vehicle_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key = True)
    schema_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    option_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    record_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50L, blank=True)
    data_value = models.CharField(max_length=255L,primary_key = True)
    condition = models.TextField(blank=True)

    unique_together = (('vehicle_id','schema_id','option_id','data_value','record_id'))

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'equipment'

class OptionList(models.Model):

    vehicle_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key = True)
    option_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)

    option_type = models.CharField(max_length=10L)
    option_code = models.CharField(max_length=255L, blank=True)
    manuf_name = models.CharField(max_length=255L)
    #...

    unique_together = (('vehicle_id','option_id'),)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'option_list'
```

Now, I want to load all entries from OptionList for a given vehicle_id and, for each option, join in the SchemaCategories that apply to it. OptionList and SchemaCategory are related through the Equipment table (vehicle_id and option_id yields schema_id, which can be used to get all categories). Right now I'm using a MySQL query that looks like this:

```sql
select A.option_type, 
    A.option_code, 
    A.manuf_name, 
    A.option_id,
    group_concat(distinct C.category) as category
from option_list A 
left join equipment B
on
    A.vehicle_id = B.vehicle_id 
    and
    A.option_id = B.option_id
left join schema_categories C
on
    C.language_id = 3
    and
    C.schema_id = B.schema_id
where 
    A.vehicle_id=? 
group by
    A.option_id
order by 
    A.manuf_name asc
```

Any idea how I could implement this using the Django ORM? I tried using a ManyToMany relationship between OptionList and SchemaCategory through the Equipment table, but I'm not sure how to specify the ON condition of the join using the ORM.

Comment: Can you use raw sql?  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/sql/

Comment: Well it's dirty but it does the trick. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your are looking for a way to add extra data to a many to many relationship. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755591/many-to-many-relationships-with-additional-data-on-the-relationship).  In it you also will find a link to the Django documentation explaining the topic.

Comment: Nope, not really. The problem is more that the relationships are defined through composite foreign keys rather than a single one, so adding extra data won't solve the problem.

Comment: I didn't meant add more data than you you already have. According your needs:

    **OptionList and SchemaCategory are related through the Equipment table (vehicle_id and option_id yields schema_id, which can be used to get all categories.**

 I think you should try set **Equipment** as extra data to the **SchemaCategory -- OptionList** relationship.

Comment: OK but how would you do it? ManyToManyField does not support composite keys as far as I know...

Comment: And you are right. That is not supported. So, you will have to review how your models have been written. Try answer these question. **I really need all these primary keys, or can I achieve the same result using the unique_together statement and nothing more?**

Looking at your models, I don't can think a reason for having so many primary keys. Do you really want only **one** vehicle_id in **OptionsList** table??

Comment: I'd gladly refactor the models to remove the composite primary keys, but since it's an external database (which changes often) that's not really an option. Besides, the DB layout is not so bad and having separate vehicle_id, option_id and schema_id keys in the tables makes sense since they're all needed in practice.